# Unity - PlayerPrefs.SetString appears to save garbage data

Tags: unity, c#, savegame

In Unity, I have an InputField calling this method for OnValueChanged:

```
public void SetUsername (string s) {
    username = s;
    print(s);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString ("username", s);
}
```

`print(s);` succesfully prints the typed text, but `PlayerPrefs.SetString ("username", s);` is saving what looks like garbage data. After exiting the game, here's what the relevant line of the PlayerPrefs file looks like:

```
<pref name="username" type="string">ZHNmc2Rmc2FkZg==</pref>
```

`ZHNmc2Rmc2FkZg==` isn't the string I saved...

What's going on? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because Unity does not directly write the string to the PlayerPrefs file, instead, it serializes it into a format which can be saved without conflicting with the XML. For example, it would be bad if you tried to save the string `</pref>`.

This string will appear correctly once loaded with `PlayerPrefs.GetString()`.

I figured this out while writing the question. I hope others can find this useful.

Comment: Nice information to have, thanks for sharing this.